# getText() isnt working

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine

I need the Text of an element on my site (myProfile), but the code isnt working and running the code on jasmine gives me the following error

[image]

here is my code

```
describe("login to CA", function() {
  it("returns successful", function() {
    driver.get(url);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="input-username"]')).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="input-password"]')).sendKeys(pw);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="submit"]')).click();
    myProfile = driver.findElement(By.css('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a'));
    expect(myProfile.getText()).toEqual('My profile');
  });
});
```

what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, `getText()` returns a *promise*.

If you would use [`Protractor`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/), you would be able to assert it this way (Protractor uses the patched version of jasmine and `expect()` is capable of resolving promises implicitly before making assertions).

Or, if not using Protractor, you should resolve the promise explicitly:

```
myProfile.getText().then(function (actualText) {
    expect(actualText).toEqual('My profile');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`getText` is a promise object so please try using `eventually`

```
expect(myProfile.getText()).to.eventually.be('My profile')
```

the code may change depending in the library (chai or jasmine)

please see:

**Jasmine**

https://github.com/dgrekov/jasmine_eventually

**Chai**

http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/